# How to use the Primary Key of one table as Primary Key of another using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using Hibernate, I have created two entities - Employee and EmployeeDetails. Since EmployeeDetails cannot exist without a corresponding entry in Employee, I figured I don't need an extra ID for EmployeeDetails, but could instead use the ID of the Employee entity. Here is how I have implemented this idea:

Employee-Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;
}
```

Employee-Details-Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_details")
@Data
public class EmployeeDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "e_mail", nullable = false)
    private String eMail;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employeeDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

By adding the `@MapsId` annotation to the employee-variable inside EmployeeDetails, I should be assigning the primary key of the Employee-entity to the Id-column of EmployeeDetails.

In a second step, I have written some data into both of my tables.

employee table in MySQL database:

```
employee_id    first_name    last_name    employee_details_employee_id
1              John          Smith        null
2              Jennifer      Adams        null
```

The last column was somehow generated by Hibernate. I don't understand why. It appears to be some column for identification, but I don't need it.

employee_details table in MySQL database:

```
employee_id    address    e_mail                     phone
1              null       john.smith@gmail.com       null
2              null       jennifer.adams@gmail.com   null
```

I have only assigned an e-mail to the employees. Surprisingly, there is no employee-entry in this database table. I don't really need it anyways, but I was expecting it. So yeah, I think I am doing something terribly wrong and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change mappedBy side, here useful links

https://vladmihalcea.com/change-one-to-one-primary-key-column-jpa-hibernate/
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
https://javabydeveloper.com/one-one-bidirectional-association/

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;
}
```

- 

```
Entity
@Table(name = "employee_details")
@Data
public class EmployeeDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "e_mail", nullable = false)
    private String eMail;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@MapId` is not a popular solution in work with Hibernate.
Maybe in your case, [`@Embeddable`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) will be a better option?

If I understand correctly, `EmployeeDetails` cannot exist without correlated `Employee`. So, `EmployeeDetails` could be a field in `Employee` as an embeddable field:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Embedded
    EmployeeDetails employeeDetails;
}
```

Then `EmployeeDetails` doesn't need ID and relation with the employee:

```java
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeDetails {

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "e_mail", nullable = false)
    private String eMail;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
}
```

As you can see, now in the database it's only one table `employees`, but in our hibernate model, we have two separated objects. Probably you don't need `EmployeeDetails` without `Employee` entity, so there is more efficient construction.

If you really need a separated table for `EmployeeDetails` with relation to `Employee` I recommend creating standard one-to-one mapping instead of `@MapId` construction.